# Passing int from R.id.[value] as a class constructor argument gives an NPE when I use findViewById

Tags: java, android, constructor, nullpointerexception, r.java-file

When I simply try to create a button handling class that implements onTouch and onClick events for each button I run into an issue. The following combination works (ButtonClick is my class):

```
/*Constructor*/
public ButtonClick(View v, int clickType){
    if(clickType == 0){
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    else{
        v.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
}

/*Call from Main.java*/
ButtonClick button = new ButtonClick(findViewById(R.id.button, 1);
```

However, the following gives me an NPE

```
/*Constructor*/
public ButtonClick(int buttonId, int clickType){
    if(clickType == 0){
        findViewById(buttonId).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    else{
        findViewById(buttonId).setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
}

/*Call from Main.java*/
ButtonClick button = new ButtonClick(R.id.button, 1);
```

Why can you not pass the integer value from your R configuration file as an argument without it returning a NPE, at least in this case?

Comment: What class does `ButtonClick` extends?

Comment: `findViewById` is a method of `Activity` that looks for a `View` using its id after `setContentView` is called and passes in the xml layout to look into. Post your entire `ButtonClick` class and the class that call this method and creates the NPE...

Comment: @StevenByle I think from your answer I understand the issue. Though I was extending Activity, I was not implementing onCreate (and thus setContentView). Since I don't want to actually do any of that, I will just pass the view. Good response.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **not with id**, but with **findViewById()**.
 Before calling this method, the 'layout' should be 'inflated'. ie, Instantiate a layout XML file into its corresponding View objects. Inside an Activity, usually `setContentView()` do this job. Otherwise we can use `LayoutInflater` for the same purpose.
 Important point is that the inflater instance we get, is hooked up to the current context. So, inside another context, we get null Views.